# Shell Script: Get eth name from Subnet mask

Tags: linux, shell, networking, ip, subnet

My machine has multiple ethernet device such as `eth0`, `eth1`, etc. One of those IP will have an IP in the range `192.168.x.x`. How can I fetch the device name using shell script? (Preferably using `ip` commands rather than `ifconfig`)

Like

`eth0 192.168.2.3`
or 
`eth3 192.168.5.6`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this;

```
ip -o -4 a | awk '$2 ~ "eth" { gsub(/\/.*/, "", $4); print $2" "$4}'
```

to all interfaces;

```
ip -o -4 a | awk ' { gsub(/\/.*/, "", $4); print $2" "$4}'
```

eg:

```
user@host:/tmp/$ ip -o -4 a | awk ' { gsub(/\/.*/, "", $4); print $2" "$4}'
lo 127.0.0.1
eth0 x.x.x.x
docker0 x.x.x.x

user@host:/tmp/$ ip -o -4 a | awk '$2 ~ "eth" { gsub(/\/.*/, "", $4); print $2" "$4}'
eth0 x.x.x.x
```

> man ip said :
>
> -o, -oneline
>                     output each record on a single line, replacing line feeds with the '\' character. This is convenient when you want to
>   count records with wc(1) or to grep(1) the output.
>
> -4 a :  Only show TCP/IP IPv4